# using variable in a method to another method

Tags: java, variables, methods

I started JAVA programming few days ago.As I understood , In JAVA we can't use variables in a method to another.So how can I use name array in main() method in to add() method?
This is a test code for getting name from users and putting it in an array.
Please advise me.

```
public class Library {
public static void main(String [] arg){
    System.out.println("Please Enter A Number Of Members:");
    Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
    int numOfMembers=s.nextInt();
    String name [] =new String[numOfMembers];
    int ID[]=new int[numOfMembers]; 
    add();
}
static void add(){
    System.out.println("Enter Name Of Member:");
    Scanner s2=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean x=true;
    int i=0;
    while(x==true){
        if(name[i]==null){
            name[i]=s2.nextLine();
            x=false;}
            else{ 
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use arguments. Pass the array. You could have found this with under a minute of Googling.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 ways
1. Class level variables - instead of defining the name array in main method, define it at class level and use in both main and add method
2. Pass the variable in the method add as argument.

Comment: @Farzad if you liked the answer, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark next to it.